# Foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Table1' because 'Table1' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm getting this error,
Table1 is the foreign key in the "Table",
How can i fix this error?

Foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Table1' because 'Table1' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'

```
       @if (Model != null)
                                {
                            @foreach (var items in Model)
                            {
                            @foreach (var aa in items.Table)
                            {
                               
                                @foreach ( var bb in aa.Table1)  // I have error in this object
                                {
    
                                    @foreach (var ee in bb.Table2)
                                    {
    }
}
}
}
```

Table 1 module

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace website.Models
{
    public partial class Table1
    {
        public Table1()
        {
            Table= new HashSet<Table>();
          
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? Number { get; set; }
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ResponsibleName { get; set; }  
       

        public Table2 Table2{ get; set; }
       
    }
}
```

Table model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace website.Models
{
    public partial class Table
    {
        public Table()
           
        {
            Projects = new HashSet<Projects>();
           

        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ItemId { get; set; }
        public int? ExternalId { get; set; }
        public decimal? Cost { get; set; } 


        public Table1 Table1{ get; set; }
       
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message is very clear...  Start by reading the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)

Comment: Your `Table1` does not even compile as is (where did `Table` come from?).

Comment: Questions with variables named like `Table2` are _very_ hard to visualise and assist with.

Comment: @mjwills I have joined four tables for get data from the  _table2   i will update  _table models also

Comment: @MohamedAbubakkar, `foreach` is used to iterate through items in a collection, for example the rows of a table. But you're providing the table itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach` only works on enumerable sequences. This means that the class in the `foreach` should implement `IEnumerable`. The error is that your class `Table1` does not implement this interface.

The question is: does `Table1` represent a sequence? In other words: If people order object of `Table1`: "give me your first element. And give me the next one" is there a logical answer that you can give?

If I look at your `Table1`, it seems to me that it contains a private `HashSet` in a field or property `Table`. In your example code, you forgot to define `Table`.

I guess if people want to see the `Table1` as a sequence, that they expect to see the elements stored in the HashSet. So if they ask for the first element of the sequence that `Table1` represents, they expect the first element of the HashSet.

This means that if someone asks for the first element of `Table1`, they get one `Table` object. `Table1` is a sequence of `Tables`.

You are lucky: `HashSet<Table>` also implements `IEnumerable<Table>`, so if someone asks for the Enumerator, you can simply forward the request to the HashSet.
Change your class as follows:

```
public partial class Table1 : IEnumerable<Table>, IEnumerable
{
    private HashSet<Table> Table {get;} = new HashSet<Table>();

    ...

    public IEnumerator<Table> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.Table;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Sometimes, you don't want to simply return another sequence, you want to calculate the elements one by one. In that case the most easy solution would be to use `yield return`

```
class Table1 : IEnumerable<MyClass>
{
    private HashSet<Table> myHashSet = ...

    public IEnumerator<MyClass> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (Table table in this.myHashSet)
        {
            MyClass myObject = ConvertToMyClass(table);
            yield return myObject;
        }
    }

    private MyClass ConvertToMyClass(Table table) {...}
}
```

The 'yield return' is an easy way to create an Enumerator. In the example above, I converted every element of the HashSet to a MyClass object, and `yield returned` it. This means that `GetEnumerator` returns an `IEnumerator<MyClass>`, and thus implements `IEnumerable<MyClass>`

Another example of yield return:

```
string a = ...
string b = ...
string c = ...

public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
{
    yield return a;
    yield return b;
    yield return c;
}
```

In fact, with yield return you can return every element that you want, as long as it can be converted to the type of your enumerator. Every yield return returns the next element of your sequence:

```
    yield return 1;
    yield return 1;
    yield return 5;
    yield return 2;
    yield return 2;
    yield return 2;
```

This represents the sequence on int [1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 2]

Comment: "This means that the class in the foreach should implement IEnumerable." That's wrong. You don't need to implement the `IEnumerable` interface, you only need to have a public parameterless GetEnumerator method that returns something that resembles an `IEnumerator`. That's one of the places where the c# compiler is relying on [duck typing.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#:~:text=Duck%20typing%20in%20computer%20programming,determined%20by%20an%20object's%20type.)